# Converting part of a subversion repo to git

Tags: git, svn, migration

First of all let me say: I've got a pretty rounded knowledge of git, but only a basic understanding of subversion.
Right:
I have been tasked with porting a subversion repo to git. The challenge is that i don't need the nested project, but rather i need to seperate out a folder further down, and create a new git repository from that.

The structure of the subversion repo is as follows:

```
http://path/to/repo/
->project1
->project2
  ->tags
    ->path/to/targetProject
  ->branches
    ->path/to/targetProject
  ->trunk
    ->path/to/targetProject
```

What is want is to create a new git repository that only includes the folder "targetProject" of project2. I have been messing around with svn2git and git-svn, but so far i have only seen options to migrate the entire project2 structure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is located on that link:http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html

It's about using svndumpfilter, that builds a dump of your full dumped repository that contains only the filtered ones, one example that solves your question is the next:

```
$svndumpfilter include --targets FILE < fullDumpfile > filteredDumpFile
```

Where the content of the 'FILE' is:

```
/project2
/tags/path/to/project
/branches/path/to/project
/trunk/path/to/project
```

To obtain your first dumpfile, you have to run the next command (supposing you're on the svn server)

```
$svn dump --bypass-prop-validation -q path/to/your/repo > fullDumpFile.dmp
```

If you moved projects inside the starting svn probably you will have a little problems on your filter cause of dependencies.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly: Make a new subversion repo containing only the relevant files, and migrate a GIT repo from that?

Comment: Exactly, you build a new repo that is a Filtered repo containing only the project you want to migrate

Answer (score -1):

Just use git-svn, you can specify which svn dir contains trunk in case svn repo does not use standard layout:

```
git svn init <url> --trunk=project2/trunk/path/to/targetProject
git svn fetch
```

It's neatly explained in [git-svn man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html).

[edit]
Since svn does not have notion of tags or branches (only "copies"), then in your case you won't be able to automatically convert them to git (because there is no svn dir, that contains copies of targetProject dir). But you can work around this by treating selected svn dirs as branches of targetProject. After initial fetch is finished, add following line to your .git/config for each branch, that you want:

```
branches = project2/branches/{<branch_name>}/path/to/targetProject:refs/remotes/*
```

So in the end, section will look like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://repo-url
    fetch=project2/trunk/path/to/targetProject
    branches = project2/branches/{branch_one}/path/to/targetProject:refs/remotes/*
    branches = project2/branches/{branch_two}/path/to/targetProject:refs/remotes/*
```

And do git svn fetch after that.